# Parsing rails uploaded temporary file more then once

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I'm currently trying to parse an uploaded file to rails. However, after I "read" the file once I cannot read it again. From what I've read online it appears that rails immediately deletes the uploaded file. Is there a way to make the file persistent? My code is as follows

```
  file_param = params[:sequence]

  file_param.read.each do |l|
    # do stuff
  end

  file_param.read.each do |l|
    # do stuff again. this is not being called.
  end
```

I've thought of using paperclip or some other storage gem, but I don't need to store the files, simply read their contents. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it into an array, if you really need to go over it multiple times, or just save it.